# Cordova how to use drawables

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, drawable

Got a html file that uses a background image.
I want to add the background-image according the the size of the phone.
I've learnt about the

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="www/res/drawable-hdpi/yourImage.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/yourImage.png" />
</platform>
```

statement, that adds the drawable in the right folder.
My question is, what to put in the html/(css) file so that later, the right background should be used according to the phone's size.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Solved, here's the solution for the new commers:

```
initBackground: function(){
    var value = "url(\"img/Sign-in-background/Sign-in-background-";
    if(screen.width <= 200 && screen.height <= 320)
        value += "ldpi-portrait.png\")";
    else if(screen.width <= 320 && screen.height <= 480)
        value += "mdpi-portrait.png\")";
    else if(screen.width <= 480 && screen.height <= 800)
        value += "hdpi-portrait.png\")";
    else
        value += "xhdpi-portrait.png\")";
    alert(value);
    var body = document.querySelector("#body");
        body.style.backgroundImage = value;
}
```